# Laravel 5.6 pagination (Model.links()) always displaying the first page

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I am reading a book and I am frustated because it doesn't change my pages.

I created a new resourceful controlller and my index method is like this:

```
  public function index()
{

    $events = Event::paginate(10);

    return view('events.index')->with('events', $events);
}
```

in my index.blade.php

```
 @extends('layouts.app')

 @section('content')

<h1>Events</h1>

<ul>
    @forelse($events as $event)
        <li>{{  $event->name }}</li>
        @empty
            <li>No events found!</li>
        @endforelse
</ul>

{!!  $events->links() !!}  // links are generate 1 2 3 4 but cannot navigate only the first page is displayed

@endsection
```

Updated: generated html

```
 <ul class="pagination" role="navigation">

 <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="&laquo; Previous">
            <span class="page-link" aria-hidden="true">&lsaquo;</span>
        </li>          

 <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page"><span class="page-link">1</span></li>

<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="http://localhost/events?page=2">2</a></li>

<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="http://localhost/events?page=3">3</a></li>

<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="http://localhost/events?page=4">4</a></li>

<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="http://localhost/events?page=5">5</a></li>

 <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="http://localhost/events?page=6">6</a></li>

<li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="http://localhost/events?page=2" rel="next" aria-label="Next &raquo;">&rsaquo;</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: What's the generated HTML?

Comment: So all pages show the same events?